# Somar valores decimal mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Fiz uma query que soma um campo decimal, só que estou tendo problema, pois quando eu coloco a clausula `group by t1.id_sell` ele me lista as vendas mas já não soma corretamente e sem a clausula soma correto mas só me retorna uma linha.

query:

```
SELECT Sum(t1.preco_sell) AS result_sum, t1.*, t2.name, t3.name_produto 
FROM   tb_sell t1 
       INNER JOIN tb_user t2 
               ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user 
       INNER JOIN tb_produtos t3 
               ON t1.id_produto = t3.id_produto 
WHERE  t1.status = 2 
GROUP  BY t1.id_sell
```

Comment: Seria legal que você criasse tabelas com estrutura e conteúdo minimos que reproduzisse o problema e postasse junto à questão para facilitar o trabalho de quem se propõe responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no seu nos campos que você exibe no seu `Select`, no na sua junção no `Group By`

Caso você queria exibir a soma de todos os itens vendidos em uma nova coluna, o que você deve fazer é uma *SubQuery* para isso

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name, t3.name_produto,
(SELECT Sum(preco_sell)
    FROM   tb_sell
    WHERE  status = 2
)AS result_sum
FROM   tb_sell t1
       INNER JOIN tb_user t2
               ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user
       INNER JOIN tb_produtos t3
               ON t1.id_produto = t3.id_produto
WHERE  t1.status = 2
```

Quando você manda exibir todos os itens de *t1* a consulta não ira conseguir agrupar, já que todos os campos, provavelmente, tem valores diferentes e com isso não está retornando o que você deseja

Comment: Jeferson essa query tb nao deu certo :/

Comment: vc poderia informar o que vc realmente espera no retorno da query, junto com os campos

Comment: quero que me retorne a soma dos valores das vendas juntamente com todas as vendas apenas separada pela clausura where status = 2 (cod de vendido na aplicaçao)

Comment: esse eh so o principio, pois depois a intençao eh colocar uns filtros

Comment: No caso vc quer q mostre todas as informações da sua tabela de vendas e um campo ao lado com o total gerado de todas as suas vendas, sem ser agrupado por nd?

Comment: na vdd eu sou novo usando o group by jeferson entao pra mim eh tanto quanto novo ainda usar ela..entao to apanhando um pouco rs.. mas a intençao eh essa msm

Comment: No caso, o que vc precisa é de uma subquery que vai te retornar essa soma, qnd vc usa o `group by ` ele vai agrupar pelas seus campos que estão no select, então n tem como exibir essas 2 informações dessa maneira, vou editar a query e vc tenta com ela

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56316/discussion-between-jeferson-almeida-and-flavio-domingos).